# Hold the title to

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Hold the title to -- What does this phrase mean? I read it in following context:

> I think as early as 1947 he **held the title to** the family home, even
>   though his father would live until 1955.

Comment: ownership of the house

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Hold the  title  is  a  way  of  saying  legally  that  you own  something**

The  sentence  means  that he became  the  owner  of  the  house  legally in1947  ( He got  the  title  deeds) for the  house, although his   father  would live untle  1955.

It  is  rather  surprsing that  how  could he  know  that  his  father  would  live  untill  1955.

Comment: If the last comment is intended seriously - of course the sentence was written at a more recent date.